# How to write static_files exclude one subdirectory in yaml of Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

With app.yml in GAE, we use regular expressions to match a certain type of url address.

If I want to match a subdirectory of the path which is not a particula string(exclude one ), I do not know how to write regular expression?

For example:

I want to upload **foo/bar/.*** as static files **exclude** any files in **foo/bar/dir/.*** , how to deal with this in app.yaml .

**include** files in dir as static files like :

```
foo/bar/main.css
foo/bar/js/main.js
```

**exclude** files in dir(to use these files as application templates) like this:

```
foo/bar/views/index.html
```

The reason why I need this function is that I have  mixed templates file with static files in a parent file. like Wordpress theme templates file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people keep all their static files in a subdirectory called "public" or "static" to avoid this issue, and I recommend you do the same.

You could add a line to catch your files by extension like:

```
- url: /foo/bar/([^.]+\.(js|css))
  static_files: foo/bar/\1
  upload: foo/bar/[^.]+\.(js|css)
```

Comment: Is there no regex could exclude one subdictory?

Comment: or a regex (POSIX Extended compliant) to exclude a specific file extension?